# How can I get NavigationService and navigate from a backdoor method?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to navigate from a backdoor so that I can bypass a certain screen when running my UITests.

Here's my code:

AppDelegate.cs

```
[Export("bypassInitialGuidePage:")]
public NSString BypassInitialGuidePage(NSString noValue)
{
    BackdoorHelpers.BypassInitialGuidePage();
    return new NSString();
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Export("BypassInitialGuidePage")]
public void BypassInitialGuidePage() => BackdoorHelpers.BypassInitialGuidePage();
```

BackdoorHelpers.cs

```
public static class BackdoorHelpers
{
#if DEBUG
    public static void BypassInitialGuidePage() 
    {
        new SettingsService().InitialGuideDone = true;

        // Add navigation logic here

    }
#endif
}
```

The `BypassInitialGuidePage()` method is being called successfully from the tests. However, I need help with getting the `NavigationService` so I can navigate away from current page.

I'm using `Prism.Forms v7.1.0.431` and I've tried the solutions in https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1032 but they are not working with the latest version.